# List<class> how to get subtotal

Tags: c#, linq, list

What would be the simplest way to sum up all the TestScore that are the same SUBJECT and put the total value to each instance?

```
public class TestScore
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SUBJECT { get; set; }
    public int SCORE { get; set; }
    public int SUBTOTAL { get; set; }
}

List<TestScore> testScores = new List<TestScore>{
    new TestScore{ ID = 0, SUBJECT = "MATH", SCORE = 10},
    new TestScore{ ID = 1, SUBJECT = "MATH", SCORE = 20},
    new TestScore{ ID = 2, SUBJECT = "ENGLISH", SCORE = 10},
    new TestScore{ ID = 3, SUBJECT = "ENGLISH", SCORE = 20},
    new TestScore{ ID = 4, SUBJECT = "ENGLISH", SCORE = 30},    
};
```

Is there something like?

```
foreach (TestScore ts in testScores)
{
    ts.SUBTOTAL = Sum(testScores.SUBJECT == ts.SUBJECT);
}
```

Comment: you could use `GroupBy`.

Comment: Should all scores with the same subject have the same subtotal? Or should that be a running number, i.e. ID = 0 would have subtotal 10 and ID = 1 would have subtotal 30?

Comment: You haven't assigned a value to type in any of the `TestScore` objects you added to the `testScores`.

Comment: GroupBy or an easy Linqcommand

Comment: @BernhardHofmann: How is that relevant?

Comment: Design wise the total value shouldn't be stored in each instance. It's not data specific to an instance. You could put it in a dictionary<Type, SubTotal>

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The question asks for sum by the same TYPE.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann: The sample code clearly shows that she meant `SUBJECT`.

Comment: Pedantry wise the field names should not be all capitals

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I've assumed you're correct and corrected the question. :)

Comment: While you're correcting, `SCORE` and `SUBTOTAL` are inconsistent, as well.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: I don't think so. Why do you say that?

Comment: I misread, ignore me, too early, must get coffee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided that you declare a `SUBJECT` property in `TestScores` definition, this is what you need:

```
var grouped = testScores.GroupBy(ts=>ts.SUBJECT)
                        .Select(g => new {SUBJECT = g.Key, 
                                          Sum = g.Sum(ts=> ts.SCORE)});
```

The result will be an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type, where each instance will have `SUBJECT` and `Sum` members.

Answer (score 2):

```
testScores
    .GroupBy(ts => ts.SUBJECT)
    .Select(g => new {
        Subject = g.Key, 
        Sum = g.Select(x => x.SCORE).Sum()
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you are after.

```
public class TestScore
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int TYPE { get; set; }
    public int SCORE { get; set; }
    public string SUBJECT { get; set; }
}

List<TestScore> testScores = new List<TestScore>{
    new TestScore{ ID = 0, SUBJECT = "MATH", SCORE = 10},
    new TestScore{ ID = 1, SUBJECT = "MATH", SCORE = 20},
    new TestScore{ ID = 2, SUBJECT = "ENGLISH", SCORE = 10},
    new TestScore{ ID = 3, SUBJECT = "ENGLISH", SCORE = 20},
    new TestScore{ ID = 4, SUBJECT = "ENGLISH", SCORE = 30},    
};

var tsList = from ts in testScores 
             group new {ts.SUBJECT,ts.SCORE} by ts.SUBJECT into grp 
             select new { Subject = grp.Key, Subtotal = grp.Sum(x => x.SCORE) };

foreach(var t in tsList)
    Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0} - Subtotal: {1}", t.Subject, t.Subtotal);

Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Exit...");    
Console.ReadKey();
```